# Is possible to build compound component with separated files? REACT

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand React's compound pattern. In all exercises all components are in one file. Is it possible to build component with that pattern with external components?

I would achieve that scenario:

src:
components:
Main
Component1
Component2
Component3

// ONE FILE Main.js
import {CompoundComponent1, CompoundComponent2, CompoundComponent3} './foo'

```
const Main = () => {
 const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false)
 const toggle = () => setOn(!on)
 const CompoundComponent1 = Component1;
 const CompoundComponent2 = Component2;
 const CompoundComponent3 = Component3;

 return <Switch on={on} onClick={toggle} />
}

Main.C1 = CompoundComponent1
Main.C2 = CompoundComponent2
Main.C3 = CompoundComponent3

// ONE FILE END


App.js

const App = () => {
<Main>
<Main.C1>FOO</Main.C1>
// etc.
</Main>
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what Switch component does?

Comment: This is just pseudo code. Don't focus on that

Comment: Well if you mean to use Main.C1 outside of the component file, you can't.

Comment: @LightBulb so if i'm using Coumpound Pattern, then i must write all components in one file?

Comment: No you can write each component in different files and import it to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that i found solution.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {Switch} from '../switch'
import {ToggleOn} from './02/ToggleOn'
import {ToggleOff} from './02/ToggleOff'
import {ToggleButton} from './02/ToggleButton'

function Toggle() {
  const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false)
  const toggle = () => setOn(!on)

  return <Switch on={on} onClick={toggle} />
}

Toggle.ToggleOn = ToggleOn
Toggle.ToggleOff = ToggleOff
Toggle.ToggleButton = ToggleButton

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Toggle>
        <Toggle.ToggleOn>Turn ON</Toggle.ToggleOn>
        <Toggle.ToggleOff>Turn OFF</Toggle.ToggleOff>
        <Toggle.ToggleButton />
      </Toggle>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

In separated files:

```
export const ToggleButton = ({on, toggle}) => (
  <Switch on={on} onClick={toggle} />
)


export const ToggleOn = ({on, children}) => {
  if (on) {
    return children
  }
  return null
}
```