# How to: Deeply nested compound componets with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the following component three with the compound component pattern:

```
export const Screen = () => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Content>
        <Card.Content.Action>
      
        </Card.Content.Action>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

I have usually seen this pattern with [one nesting level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73353854/8582246), but I would like to add one/N more level(s).

```
const Card = () => {};
const CardContent = () => {};
const CardContentAction = () => {};

Card.Content = CardContent;
Card.Content.Action = CardContentAction; // how could I get this nesting level?
Card.Content.Action.Other = CardContentActionOther // or N nesting levels?
```

In this scenario, `Card.Content` it’s both a parent and a child. it’s a child of the `Card` component, but it’s also a parent to the `Card.Content.Action` component. **How could I structure the typescript types to achieve this pattern?**

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the deep nested property assignment code that was written:

```
Card.Content = CardContent;
Card.Content.Action = CardContentAction; // how could I get this nesting level?
Card.Content.Action.Other = CardContentActionOther // or N nesting levels?
```

This will cause TypeScript to complain:

> Property 'Action' is missing in type '({ children }: Props) => JSX.Element' but required in type 'CardContentType'.

TypeScript is fine as long as you assign the properties directly on the parent components:

```
Card.Content = CardContent
CardContent.Action = CardContentAction
CardContentAction.Other = CardContentActionOther
```

A complete solution looks like:

```
import type { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode
}

interface CardType {
  ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element
  Content: CardContentType
}

interface CardContentType {
  ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element
  Action: CardContentActionType
}

interface CardContentActionType {
  ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element
  Other: () => JSX.Element
}

const Card: CardType = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <>{children}</>
}

const CardContent: CardContentType = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <>{children}</>
}

const CardContentAction: CardContentActionType = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <>{children}</>
}

const CardContentActionOther = () => {
  return <></>
}

Card.Content = CardContent
CardContent.Action = CardContentAction
CardContentAction.Other = CardContentActionOther

export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Content>
        <Card.Content.Action>
          <Card.Content.Action.Other />
        </Card.Content.Action>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  )
}
```